# Imagemagick: disable OpenCL on Linux

Tags: linux, imagemagick, opencl

Whenever I use imagemagick commands, I see errors and warnings like the following:

```
$ convert -size 99x99  caption:"t" -border 1x1 t.png
convert: clBuildProgram failed. (-11) @ warning/opencl.c/CompileOpenCLKernels/1097.
convert: clCreateCommandQueue failed. (0) @ warning/opencl.c/InitOpenCLEnvInternal/1424
```

I assume this is because of faulty or incomplete open source ati drivers on Linux.

How can I prevent Imagemagick from using OpenCL, without re-compiling it? I prefer to just use the version provided by my Linux distribution of choice - Arch Linux in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to disable OpenCL support without recompiling ImageMagick. Setting the environment variable `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE` to `OFF` will disable OpenCL. This will work for both ImageMagick 6 and 7.

Comment: This does work, thanks! `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=OFF convert -size 99x99  caption:"t" -border 1x1 t.png`